# SBS 2011: Disabling WSUS

Tags: wsus, windows-sbs-2011

I have a client with an SBS 2011 server that hosts their email, company data, and hosts a few other business services.  The system has plenty of RAM; however their issue is HDD access time.  The wait time for file access is horrendous. I have found that the SQL DB for WSUS is almost constantly paging the HDD.

My initial thought is to just disable the WSUS and related services. I am not on-site at this facility.

What ramifications are likely to occur from just disabling WSUS?  or is there another solution to solve WSUS constantly accessing the HDD?

Comment: Please check in which partition does the WSUS DB resides. Is it in the default C: or in any other partition? If it's in the default location, try migrating to say, D: and monitor the progress for some time.

Comment: Currently only one partition on this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main ramification is workstations not getting updated, assuming they're using WSUS.

Microsoft provides a [WSUS reindexing script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6f8cde49-5c52-4abd-9820-f1d270ddea61) that might help if they're actually using WSUS for updates.  I've found that that and running the cleanup wizard's tasks (not the wizard itself) helps a lot (I've scheduled Microsoft's [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WSUS-Server-Cleanup-f33d2658) for that).  Those may or may not provide enough of an improvement to keep it running.

Comment: Did not fix all of the server's issues, but it helped at least temporarily. Thank you for the response! Sorry for taking a few years to accept your answer. ;)

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad it helped, even if it was temporary.